# Magento 2 : Can Not Add HTML Content in Notice Message From Controller

Tags: magento2.4, html

If I go to: `\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Login::execute`
and add this code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class);
$url = 1;
$this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(
    $request->escapeHtml(
        __('AAASomething went wrong, please contact our <a href="%s">customer service</a>!', $url),
        ['a']
    )
);
```

I m NOT getting my html code. I see this:
[image]
What am i doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the Following to get the HTML in Message :

> **In di.xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\MessageConfigurationsPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configurationsMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customHtml" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="renderer" xsi:type="const">\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\Renderer\BlockRenderer::CODE</item>
                    <item name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName::messages/customHtml.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

The template file could then look like this :

> view/adminhtml/templates/messages/customHtml.phtml

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getData('url'))?>"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('click here first')) ?></a>
```

We need to invoke this message and pass in the url information as part of the data Array:

```
$this->messageManager->addComplexNoticeMessage(
'customHtml',
[
    'url' => $this->_helper->getUrl('to/our/route')
]
);
```

Expected Result :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this way,

```
$message = __('AAASomething went wrong, please contact our, <a href="%1">customer service</a>',$this->urlModel->getUrl('Your Address'));

$this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($message);
```